# MVC Connecting to Database and returning data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm simply after wanting to render some data from my database into a page view using MVC.

My controller method is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT top 10 Keys FROM dbo.TestTable";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }


    return View();
}
```

The corresponding model is super simple:

```
public string Keys{ get; set; }
```

I've debugged this and it is connecting to my database properly. I've run the SQL query in my database and it returns results. However, when I run the below code I get a -1 result value.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit the console write line with the real return code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT top 10 Keys FROM dbo.TestTable";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                  result.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
}


    return View(result);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in model)
    <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out the result form it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
```

`reader[0]` here means to get the value of the first column of the result set from the table which is fetched.

or you can also specify the column name like:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["Keys"]));
```